# .change() won't fire because of Default Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form of number inputs, that I assign default values to. However, by assigning default value to the inputs, now the `.change()` event will not trigger when I type into and change the actual **"values"** of the inputs.

I've tried `.val()` & `.keypress()` but no luck.

The HTML:

```
<form id="target">
    <h4>% Coal generation:<input type="number"></h4>
    <h4>% Biomass generation:<input type="number"></h4>
    <h4>% Geothermal generation:<input type="number"></h4>
    <input id="submitprofile" type="submit" class="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

The JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("target").elements[0].defaultValue=Number(studentdata["Coal"]);// 10
    document.getElementById("target").elements[1].defaultValue=Number(studentdata["Biomass"]);//20
    document.getElementById("target").elements[2].defaultValue=Number(studentdata["Geothermal"]);//0
   $( "#target" ).change(function() {
       console.log('form changed');//not happening!
       refreshdisplay();
   });
 });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3e0mczxj/1/ ?

Comment: Works for me. I assume you have checked the console for any error

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign your change-handler to the inputs of your form like this:

```
$( "#target :input" ).change(function() {
        console.log('form changed');//not happening!
        refreshdisplay();
    });
```

e.g. here: http://jsfiddle.net/fhc3fywc/1/

if you really want to have the `refreshDisplay`-function get called everytime you enter a number, replace `.change` with `.keyPress`. 
I'd suggest to add a delay for this using setTimeout or something similar, cause adding for example "111" directly into the form field would fire three times, one time for every number entered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the `input` field's change inside instead of the `form`

```
 $( "#target").find("input").on("change", function() {
       console.log('form changed');
       //refreshdisplay();
   });
```